# How to write bitbucket pipeline for deploying my angular universal app?

Tags: angular, pipeline, continuous-deployment, angular-universal, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy my angular universal app on server through bitbucket pipeline. I have written scripts in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` as follows:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build app
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - npm run build:ssr
          - npm run serve:ssr
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
```

My `package.json` has following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve -c=dev -o",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server",
        "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
    },
```

When `npm run serve:ssr` executes, I see that it gives same output as on localhost i.e. `Node server listening on http://localhost:4000`. It gets stuck at this point. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a remote server you can see below a sample of .yml file

```
image: node:10

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Installation
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
          artifacts:
            - node_modules/** # Save modules for next steps
      - step:
          name: Lint
          script:
            - npm run lint
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - npm run build:production
          artifacts:
            - dist/** # Save build for next steps
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          script:
            - echo "$(ls -la)"
            - echo "$(ls -la dist)"
            - ssh user@your-server rm -rf /var/www/www.your-domain.net/html/your-app
            - scp -r dist/your-app user@your-server:/var/www/your-domain.at/html/your-app
```